On a webpage, how do I make an element subject to a click (and jump to a link), but not subject to a tap?
This actually can be an advanced topic, or maybe there is a simple method to solve it.
The issue:

Let's say, if there are 5 or 25 small pictures, and the user can move the mouse over (mouse hover) to see the slightly enlarged version of picture (or in some case, the picture will actually become a tiny video and play for a few seconds as a preview).

Right now, the user cannot click that image or video to jump to a link. There is a separate button underneath that says "Go" to jump to the link.

The Program Manager hopes that clicking on the picture will let the user jump to the link.

So to solve this issue, I can use a <a href="... ">. </a> to wrap around this element to achieve this.

However, on the iPad or iPhone, or any "touch screen" PC, the user may tap on it, and immediately jump to that link, without the chance to see the enlarged picture or the small video playing

So the PM (Program Manager) doesn't like this behavior, and says, "OK, only jump to that link when it is the Desktop situation." So the PM means, when it is iPad or iPhone or touch screen, when the user taps on that small picture, don't jump to the link.

The PM just hopes that a "click" on the picture can let the user jump to the link on a PC, but it creates the undesirable effect on iPad or iPhone or touch screen, as mentioned in (5) above: a tap will also jump, without the hovering effect to see the picture enlarged or the tiny video preview.


So the question is, how do I make it so that the click and jump only works on the Desktop but no iPad, iPhone or touch screen?
After some thinking, my initial attempt is to: when there is a mouseenter event, add a class to the element, called mouse-entered (and on a mouseleave event, remove that class). So then, if the element doesn't have this mouse-entered class, then invoke ev.preventDefault() to prevent the jumping to the link.
The code is:

      elContent.addEventListener("mouseenter", (ev) => {
        console.log("MOUSE_ENTER", ev, new Date());
        elContent.classList.add("mouse-entered");
      });

      elContent.addEventListener("mouseleave", (ev) => {
        console.log("MOUSE_LEAVE", ev, new Date());
        elContent.classList.remove("mouse-entered");
      });

      elContent.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
        console.log("CLICK", ev, new Date(), performance.now(), Date.now());

        if (!elContent.classList.contains("mouse-entered")) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
      });

and you can try it on the codesandbox:
The code is on:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/blissful-hugle-xszzzh
and the page is on:
https://xszzzh-5000.csb.app/
so if you view it as a webpage or if you use Google Chrome's dev tool to simulate an iPhone or iPad, if you tap on the block, you will still jump to the link (I set it to jump to google.com).
The reason is: before the click event fires for the tapping (on an iPhone), the mousenenter event is also fired.  So the class mouse-entered is in fact added, (and no mouseleave event is fired to remove that class), so it won't work.
My second thought is: what if I add a class, such as tapped, and use ev.preventDefault() when there is a tapped class, so that I know if it is iPhone or iPad, then don't jump to the link.  However, there are computers with a touch screen, so if the user tapped on it, and then use the trackpad to move the mouse over and click on it, it should still jump to the link, so it won't work either.
The sequence of the event is:

touchstart
touchend
mouseneter
click

So I cannot say, "if there is a touchend, make it go back to the non-touch-screen case", because on the iPhone or iPad, it also has the touchend event fired, like on a touch screen PC.
So my third attempt is very hacky. I just use dataset to set touchend time, so that if the click event is less than 0.3 seconds or 0.5 seconds after the touchend time, then don't jump to the link. The goal is to say: if this click is actually a tap, then don't jump to the link.  It works, but it is really hacky.
(the dataset is like, it will add a data-some-name as an attribute to the element)
The code is like:
      const elContent = document.querySelector("#content");
      console.log("elContent", elContent);

      elContent.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
        console.log("CLICK", ev, new Date(), performance.now(), Date.now());

        if (
          elContent.dataset.touchEndedAt &&
          Date.now() - +elContent.dataset.touchEndedAt < 500
        ) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
      });

      elContent.addEventListener("touchend", (ev) => {
        console.log("TOUCH_END", ev, new Date(), performance.now(), Date.now());
        elContent.dataset.touchEndedAt = Date.now();
      });

You can try. The code is https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-dirac-rm8h7w
and the app is https://rm8h7w.csb.app/
So if you use Google Chrome to view the page as on a PC or Mac, you click on the block and it will jump to the link (google.com), but if you use the dev tool to simulate an iPhone and tap on it, then it won't jump.
But it is quite hacky.  Is there a better way?
P.S. It is possible to detects whether it is a device with a mouse or with hovering possible, so we can use
      elContent.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
        if (window.matchMedia && !window.matchMedia("(pointer: fine)").matches) {
          ev.preventDefault();
        }
      });

(or by using window.matchMedia("(hover: none)").matches)
It is to tell whether the device has a mouse or trackpad or that hovering is possible on the device.  However, it seems like a partial solution, because on a PC with touch screen, there is a mouse and hovering is possible, but it is not possible to tell whether it is a "click" vs a "tap".

This question is similar to: Detect click vs. touch in JavaScript. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

it is a "similar" question, but not the same. For a PC with a touch screen, or for an iPad with a keyboard and touchpad, they may still identify themselves as "a touch device" and "no hovering", as I tried on an iPad with a keyboard and touchpad today in an Apple store. However, to tell whether that click event is a click vs a tap, is a different thing on those devices
